# Outlook 2019 Autocomplete list displaying over the top of the screen

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Yesterday Outlook suddenly changed the appearance on how address autocomplete looks like. First of all it's no longer a "compact" list, but very big "badges" (I don't know the right word for it) and secondly the first result is shown above the top of my screen so I can't even read what it is. See image below.

I have Windows 10 Professional with all the latest updates installed and MS Office Home and business 2019 (2104 build 13929.20296).

[image]

But just two days ago autocomplete looked like this:

[image]

Is there a way to revert to the old look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like this might be related to the specific Outlook version. As a temporary workaround, you could try to revert back to older Version with:
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13901.20462

as this thread: [Outlook popping up instead of dropping down](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/377921/outlook-popping-up-instead-of-dropping-down.html?childToView=381383#comment-381383) says.

You could also keep an eye on this thread to see if there would be a solution later.

Comment: This works, but I'm guessing things will break up again once Office updates again...?

Comment: Yes, reverting back to old version should only be a  temporary workaround. Let's wait and see if Microsoft would fix it in the later versions.

Comment: Update: Microsoft has published this as a known issue and would update the process in this document, remember to check it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/autocomplete-list-scrolls-off-the-screen-in-outlook-0247f165-697f-4238-b424-b03cd2582e2d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1):

The same here. Rolling back the last Windows update worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Better option:

Open your command prompt, paste the code below (including the " at the beginning) and press enter.

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13801.20266